# Open source web gallery with Exif and map support

Tags: open-source, maps, gallery, self-hosted, exif

Is there an open source web gallery I could use to present pictures and their Exif title on a map?

*Preferable* the solution should be based on OpenStreetMap and PHP. Furthermore, an option to filter based on Exif keywords would be great.

The pictures (uploaded from my mobile phone) have already a title, description, keywords and geolocation in their Exif header, so an option to edit these details is not required.

Answer (score 1):

[Piwigo](http://piwigo.org/) with the [piwigo-openstreetmap](http://piwigo.org/ext/extension_view.php?eid=701) extension works well with geolocations captured by the camera. Support for other meta data stored in the picture (e.g. keywords and description) didn't work for me out of the box, but is supposed to be supported as per their website.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can use [phTagr](http://www.phtagr.org/) Web Photo Gallery

[phTagr](http://www.phtagr.org/) has Geo Tagging that Requires google map key

Comment: phTagr requires Google Map, I was looking for OpenStreetMap.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot and an explanation? http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality Thanks!

Comment: @Toastie: The question says OSM is *preferable* so I guess this answer is still valid.